# Why do statista and other sources not list Bombay Stock Exchange despite its large market cap?

Tags: stock-market, exchange

The wikipedia [list of stock exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_exchanges) claims that both the National Stock Exchange (NSE) and the Bombay Stock Exchange(BSE) have a market cap of over 3 Trillion $.

Meanwhile sources such as [statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/270126/largest-stock-exchange-operators-by-market-capitalization-of-listed-companies/) don't even mention the BSE.

What am I missing? What is the actual market cap of NSE and BSE? Why does statista (and other sources) not mention BSE?

Comment: Neither Wikipedia nor Statista is a reputable source for stock market data. You can either look at the [website of the exchange?(https://m.bseindia.com/) or sources designed to provide market data like Bloomberg.